# AttachDistributedSequence is not supported in Unity Catalog

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, pyspark-pandas, databricks-unity-catalog

I'm trying to read a table on Databricks to a DataFrame using the `pyspark.pandas.read_table` and receive the following error:

```
AnalysisException: [UC_COMMAND_NOT_SUPPORTED] AttachDistributedSequence is not supported in Unity Catalog.;
AttachDistributedSequence[__index_level_0__#767L, _c0#734, carat#735, cut#736, color#737, clarity#738, depth#739, table#740, price#741, x#742, y#743, z#744] Index: __index_level_0__#767L
+- SubqueryAlias spark_catalog.default.diamonds
   +- Relation hive_metastore.default.diamonds[_c0#734,carat#735,cut#736,color#737,clarity#738,depth#739,table#740,price#741,x#742,y#743,z#744] csv
```

The table was created following the Databricks Quick Start notebook:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS diamonds;
 
CREATE TABLE diamonds
USING csv
OPTIONS (path "/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv", header "true")
```

I'm trying to read the table with

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
psdf = ps.read_table("hive_metastore.default.diamonds")
```

and get the error above.

Reading the table into `spark.sql.DataFrame` works fine with

```
df = spark.read.table("hive_metastore.default.diamonds")
```

The cluster versions are

```
Databricks Runtime Version 11.2
Apache Spark 3.3.0
Scala 2.12
```

I'm familiar with pandas already and would like to use `pyspark.pandas.DataFrame` since I assume it will have a familiar API and be quick for me to learn and use.

### The questions I have:

- What does the error mean?
- What can I do to read the tables to `pyspark.pandas.DataFrame`?
- Alternatively, should I just learn `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` and use that? If so, why?

Comment: are you using shared cluster?

Comment: I'm new to Databricks and don't know what that means. There's one cluster and more than 1 person in the company use that one, is that a shared cluster?

Comment: there are different policies: https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/create-cluster.html#what-is-cluster-access-mode

Comment: @AlexOtt I just ran into this, too. If I use a cluster in Single User mode, ps.read_table works. If I use a shared cluster, I get the "UC_COMMAND_NOT_SUPPORTED] AttachDistributedSequence is not supported in Unity Catalog.;" error. But I'm still unclear as to why. Could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: For now I'm just going to work around and load a spark data frame and and then use .toPandas(). I understand that loads it to memory, but that is ok in this case as it's fairly small. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AttachDistributedSequence` is a special extension used by Pandas on Spark to create a distributed index. Right now it's not supported on the Shared clusters enabled for Unity Catalog due the restricted set of operations enabled on such clusters.  The workarounds are:

- Use single-user Unity Catalog enabled cluster
- Read table using the Spark API, and then use `pandas_api` function ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.pandas_api.html)) to convert into Pandas on Spark DataFrame. (in Spark 3.2.x/3.3.x it's called `to_pandas_on_spark` ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark.html))):

```py
pdf = spark.read.table("abc").pandas_api()
```

P.S. It's not recommended to use `.toPandas` as it will pull all data to the driver node.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot! I accepted your answer as the correct one